# LayoutSerializationCallback not be called

Tags: c#, avalondock

I'm using AvalonDock and I would serialize and deserialize my layout. But the callback (where I use the ContentId for create an instance of correct object) is not always called. For this reason the loaded not work correctly. I have tried to add one "try-catch", but not thrown exception.

This is my code:

`     var layoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(manager);

```
  layoutSerializer.LayoutSerializationCallback += (s, e) =>
  {
    MyClass item;
    if (items.TryGetValue(e.Model.ContentId, out item))
    {
      e.Content = item;

      var tool = item as IMyClassToolApp;
      var anchorable = e.Model as LayoutAnchorable;

      var document = item as IMyClassDocumentApp;
      var layoutDocument = e.Model as LayoutDocument;

      if (tool != null && anchorable != null)
      {
        addToolCallback(tool);
        tool.IsVisible = anchorable.IsVisible;
        tool.IsSelected = e.Model.IsSelected;
        return;
      }

      if (document != null && layoutDocument != null)
      {
        addDocumentCallback(document);

        // Nasty hack to get around issue that occurs if documents are loaded from state,
        // and more documents are opened programmatically.
        layoutDocument.GetType().GetProperty("IsLastFocusedDocument").SetValue(layoutDocument, false, null);

        document.IsVisible = true;
        document.IsSelected = layoutDocument.IsSelected;
        return;
      }
    }

    e.Cancel = true;
  };

  try
  {
    layoutSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }`
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your stream is O.K? If for example configuration file does not exist LayoutSerializationCallback method will not be called.

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MainWindow.logger.Debug("Entering: {0}", "MainWindow_Loaded");

        string filePath = Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
            @"Jofta\Analyzer\configs\AvalonDock.config");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) && File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            XmlLayoutSerializer serializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(this.dockingManager);
            serializer.LayoutSerializationCallback += this.Serializer_LayoutSerializationCallback;
            serializer.Deserialize(filePath);
        }

        MainWindow.logger.Debug("Exiting: {0}", "MainWindow_Loaded");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MainWindow.logger.Error("Exception in: {0}", "MainWindow_Loaded");
        MainWindow.logger.Error("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}



private void Serializer_LayoutSerializationCallback(object sender, LayoutSerializationCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MainWindow.logger.Debug("Entering: {0}", "serializer_LayoutSerializationCallback");

        if (e.Model.ContentId == ObjectExplorerViewModel.AnchorableContentId)
        {
            e.Content = Workspace.Instance.ObjectExplorer;
            return;
        }

        // ...
        // ...

        MainWindow.logger.Debug("Exiting: {0}", "serializer_LayoutSerializationCallback");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MainWindow.logger.Error("Exception in: {0}", "serializer_LayoutSerializationCallback");
        MainWindow.logger.Error("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: My file is okay, I have debug the code step by step and the "Deserialize" not thrown exception.

Comment: It would be better to post more details. More fragments of the code. For example content of the config file. Have all LayoutAnchorables and LayoutDocuments their Ids?

Comment: If callback method is sometimes called and sometimes not I still think the problem is in config file in that cases. If Deserialize method won’t throw exception doesn’t matter. The configuration file has none LayoutAnchorables and LayoutDocuments for example.